# Mongo query filter by nested id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi guys I am starting to use MongoDB with NodeJS. I am not able to generate a query and I really took a look into the documentation and I could not find the answer to my question.

I have a collection like:

```
{
    _id: "Id",
    username: "name",
    cars: [
        {
            _id: "BMW Car Id"
            name: "BMW",
            colors: [{ _id: "color_red_id", "red"}, { _id: "color_blue_id", "blue"}]
        },
        {
            _id: "Mercedes Car Id"
            name: "Mercedes",
            colors: [{ _id: "color_yellow_id", "yellow"}, { _id: "color_violet_id", "violet"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to get the car "BMW" and want to filter the color with the _id (color) "color_red_id" to get something like

```
{
    _id: "Id",
    username: "name",
    cars: [
        {
            _id: "BMW Car Id"
            name: "BMW",
            colors: [{ _id: "color_red_id", "red"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

or maybe just get the "color_id" (because is the only thing I really need)

```
{
    { _id: "color_red_id", "red"}
}
```

Is that something that we can do?

Thank you and sorry for this, I think, newbie question.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it, this is a simple one:
The `$filter` filters the array as you wanted and the `$unwind` divide it into separate documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      cars: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$cars",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item.name", "BMW"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$cars"},
  {
    $project: {
      cars: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$cars.colors",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item._id", "color_red_id"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$cars"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$cars"}
  }
])
```

You can see it works on [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GBb8I-joVZD).

There are many other ways to do it:

1. `$unwind` and `$match`,
2. `$reduce` and `$filter`,
3. ...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$filter` to solve this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).